# Restrict the extentions of the Primefaces upload

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, upload

i'm trying to upload just pictures with this component

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{partyCreationBean.file}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="100000" description="Select Images" mode="simple" />
```

i tried to put also

allowTypes="jpg"

and many others combination, but still i can upload everything, and i really don't understand why.

thanks in advance,
samuele

Comment: You want to allow only jpg???

Comment: better, jpg, gif, png.

Comment: but the program allow me to insert everything... zip, doc, everything i wish.

Comment: You mean it lets you upload those files or just select those file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some extra configuration with fileUpload
Refer : http://www.mastertheboss.com/primefaces/primefaces-file-upload-example

web.xml filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Example:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="100000" description="Select Images"/>
```

This should allow your file tpypes..
You also need to ensure you have dependency jars
 Apache Commons io
 Apache Commons File Upload

Check your filter is enabled.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but what do u mean with "you also need to ensure you have dependency jars Apache commons io, Apache Commons File Upload"... i copied them into the WEB-INF/lib... then i wrote the web.xml, and then?! really sorry but i'm working with this stuff by only two weeks :/

Comment: Including the jars fulfils the dependency requirement, otherwise it woul. Be like a maven dependency if u use it

Comment: i'm sorry but still is not working... i partially solved the problem adding a check in the web bean, and displaying an error whenever the user try to upload an extension not allowed. obvisiully the idea to have already a filter is better (also for the user point of view)... but i'm not able. always the uploader shows to me any files

Answer (score 0):

`allowTypes` does not work in `mode="simple"` of `p:fileUpload`!

You can use `mode="advanced"` in order to be able to restrict file extensions.

Comment: Well, actually it does work. At least on PrimeFaces 7.0

Comment: @AlexMi I'm happy that you commented on my answer! I did not work with PrimeFaces anymore since early 2017!

Answer (score 0):

If you use mode="simple", you can use the "accept" attribute. 
See: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_accept.asp